# How can I convert DNN R code into Python keras code?

Tags: python, r, keras, deep-learning

I made a DNN code in R and I would like to run it in python as well.

I tried in python as well but there was a big difference when I run it in python.

My R code is shown below.

```
dnn.f=dbn.dnn.train(x.train, y.train, hidden = c(100, 100, 100), activationfun = "sigm")
```

The code I tried in python is this.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense      
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout    
model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense(100, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(22,)) ) 
model.add( Dropout(0) ) 
model.add( Dense(100, activation='sigmoid' ) )
model.add( Dropout(0) )
model.add( Dense(100, activation='sigmoid' ) )
model.add( Dropout(0) )
model.add( Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

How can I get the similar result in python?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning you don't need to switch to python for this, keras is available in R. You can define a similar model using keras in R like this:

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential(input_shape = c(22)) %>%
  layer_dense(100, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(.4) %>%
  layer_dense(100, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(.4) %>%  
  layer_dense(100, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(.4) %>%
  layer_dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer = 'adam', metrics = 'accuracy')
model # prints summary by default
```

Comment: Thank you for kind reply. But I think it's little bit difficult for me to plot learning curve and try other method in R so I try to implement this code in python to get similar results.

Comment: However I didn't know "dbn.dnn" function in R is using "relu" activation function in hidden layers. Thank you!!